# codeblocks - compile with large-adress-aware flag

Tags: c++, memory, gcc, mingw, codeblocks

How can I compile a 32-bit app on a 64-bit system with the `LARGE_ADRESS_AWARE` flag using Codeblocks? I need to use more memory than 2GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be a case of adding `-Wl,--large-address-aware` to the linking flags. I don't use CodeBlocks, so can't tell you how you do that step by step, but I'm sure there is a "Linking Options" component in your project settings that you can add this string into.

The Linker options:
http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/ld/Options.html

Edit: Of course, if you have a modern enough gcc-mingw on your system, you should be able to give it -m64 for the compile and link stages, and get a native 64-bit app, at which point you can use as much memory as you like (well, until you exhaust either swap space or 48 bits of address range, whichever comes first - probably swap space - unless you have more than 256TB of disk-space...)

Comment: It is still using SWAP, when it reach the 2GB (1,3GB on VRAM, 800 mb on RAM) and need some more.
Actual memory usage: 1,3GB on VRAM, 0,8GB on RAM, 0,8GM on SWAP, Free memory(ram) 1.500GB...

Comment: That's something else - probably windows being daft as usual. Swapping has nothing to `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`. To prove that, try to write a piece of code that just allocates a lot of memory - say chunks of 100MB, and see how many you can allocate with and without `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` (you can also check that it actually WORKS by writing to a byte every 1M or so in each block - you don't want to fill the whole thing, as it will take several seconds to fill a couple of GB of ram, even if it's NOT swapping). Unfortunately, I don't know of a "don't be daft with me" flag... Use linux?