# Increasing (nonstack) memory used by a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, 32bit-64bit

I am running a heavy memory intensive job on a windows OS with 12 GB of RAM. By my computations, 4 GB of memory should be enough to run the program. I am running the program I've written with dynamic memory allocation (I have 2 versions of the program in C and C++ with `malloc`/`free` and `new`/`delete` respectively) using CodeBlocks.

When I pull up task manager, I see that the program only seems to use about 2 GB of RAM, even when I have a lot more available, and the pagefile size is currently set to 30 GB. Is there any way I can get CodeBlocks to use more memory? I also used DEV-C++ and I get the same bad_alloc error in the C++ code.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
Oh and I am using a 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: I'll assume you're using a 32 bit version of Windows in which case the answer is no. If you're using a 64 bit version of Windows you could build a 64-bit binary that would provide access to all system memory.

Comment: I am using a 64 bit windows os 7.

Comment: Sounds like you're compile for a 32bit target. Which compiler are you using exactly?

Comment: You'll need to create a 64-bit program to take advantage of the large virtual memory address space available to processes on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: By default 32bit processes are created with 2gb of user accessible address space, there is a way to increase that default to 3gb. 64bit applications shouldn't have that restriction - so as someone has already mentioned, you are most likely building a 32bit executable.

Comment: Side note; don't think of memory as "RAM", think of it as (virtual) address space.  Unless you are specifically allocating to RAM you are using virtual memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all the help so far. There was a simple workaround. I installed mingw 64bit compiler, pointed code blocks to that compiler and everything worked like a charm. yay.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this page for memory limits based on architecture (x86, 64-bit) and Windows version. Some work-arounds are mentioned:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#memory_limits

First you have to make sure you are building a 64-bit executable and not 32-bit.
**If using g++, make sure you use option `-m64`**.

---

As for large address awareness mentioned in the MSDN page, it should be active by default on 64-bit Windows systems.
Still, the Visual C++ linker has an option to explicitly ask for it: `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`

Now if you don't use the Visual C++ linker, it appears you can always use this as an extra step if you want to activate large address awareness for your executable:

```
editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE your_executable
```

(editbin being an M$ Visual Studio tool)

Comment: A workaround for dev-c++/code-block may be to use the ms's ld.exe. http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=12183.45

Comment: Ohw, sorry, I read too fast. Looks like you could use editbin (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to allow more memory to the compiled binary.

Comment: looks like i have to download editbin.exe - does this look like a good place to download it from? http://originaldll.com/file/editbin.exe/39047.html

Comment: Maybe you could download `Visual Studio C++ Express Edition` and install it (not necessarily on the same machine). It's free, can always come in handy, and it should contain `editbin.exe`.

Comment: @YohanDanvin I have visual c++ express 2010 installed on the machine. I ve never used it and I have no clue how to compile a program and run using it. Googling that has come up with some solutions. I suspect I am going to be here a while figuring this out - unless you have a resource you would recommend? Thanks a ton for all the help. New windows user from linux.

Comment: You don't have to use it, just look for an `editbin.exe` in the install and use as I wrote in my answer. But only if needed! First make sure you read the part in bold in my answer. :)

Comment: @YohanDanvin    If I use the visual c++ compiler will it automatically generate a 64 bit binary? Also, do you know if it possible to compile a c program with 'cl' the default visual c++ compiler? I am trying to compile my c program under cl and not ahving success but I think  i ll figure it out soon.

Comment: You should open a different question for that, maybe 2. Getting way off topic here.

Comment: @user1775614 Just compile your program as a 64 bit program, it should provide this flag by default. If the gcc compiler you're using is old, so it doesn't add that flag, do this in addition to compile it as 64 bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035065/codeblocks-compile-with-large-adress-aware-flag