# QMake - How and where to add linker flag?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qmake, linker-flags

I tried to add the following in the `.pro` file of our project:

```
win32 {
    ...
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS += -Wl,--large-address-aware

}
```

I get an error `LINK : warning LNK4044: Nicht erkannte Option /Wl,--large-address-aware; wird ignoriert.`

Translation:  `unrecognised option /Wl,--large-address-aware; gets ignored.`

Before that I tried to find out where to add linker options but it seems to be just a normal [variable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-lflags-windows) to put in the `.pro` file. I also searched for a [searchcode entry](https://searchcode.com/file/114171641/lightscreen.pro) in which the option is part of the `.pro` file.

I added the options to increase memory limit for the 32 bit application according to [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40814-How-to-increase-available-RAM-for-Qt-Creator?p=187243#post187243) post...

I use the following Qt Kit:
[image: Qt Kit]

How to apply the option functioning?

Comment: @eyllanesc I added a complete translation...

Comment: @eyllanesc Now i get two warnings for both options `LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognised option /Wl; gets ignored.
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognised option /-large-address-aware; gets ignored.`

Comment: @eyllanesc With `"-Wl --large-address-aware"` I have exatly the same error as in my last comment. I added my Qt Kit.

Comment: I just readed your unedited comment about just trying the first option with capital letters but still the same: `unrecognised option /WL ...`

Comment: @eyllanesc `WL`: No, thats why I added the info that I want to increase memory and that I just copied it because I couldn't find anything else...

Comment: I would recommend that you use visual studio and try to activate that flag, maybe that flag is not active in your version of visual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker options in the `.pro` file are for [MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035065/codeblocks-compile-with-large-adress-aware-flag) but I am using msvc so...

I had to add the linker flags just like in the msdn documentation with a slash and the linker option in capital letters. So for [`LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wz223b1z.aspx):

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS += /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
```